# How to call a javascript function from c# code behind on Asp.net Button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, button

I want to call my facebook send dialog function from code behind :

The javascript code is :

```
function facebook_send_message(to) {
    FB.ui({
        app_id:'*****',
        method: 'send',
        name: "*****",
        link: '*****',
       to: <%=to %>,
        description:'sdf sdf sfddsfdd s d  fsf s ',
        redirect_uri: '******'


    });
}
```

The twist here is i want to call this from a dynamically generated Aspx button

```
 Button btn = new Button();
 btn.CssClass = "btn-add";
 btn.Text = "Invite";
 btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

I tried this code on the button click

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "my", "function facebook_send_message(to);", true);

}
```

However it is not working Please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add it as an attribute.

```
btn.attributes.add("OnClientClick", "javaScript: return myfunction(););
```

If `OnClientClick` doesnt work, try `onClick`. Cant remember from top of my head which one will work.

Make sure to `return false` from the JS function to prevent `Postback`.

Pseudo code:

--JS Function--

```
function myFunction() {
         alert('this is my fb function');
         return false;
}
```

--Adding button in aspx.cs page--

```
Button b = new Button();
b.ID = "btnSomeButton";
b.Text = "Call fb button";
dvButton.Controls.Add(b);
b.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return myFunction();");
```

You dont need `btn_click` event as you have in your code. You also dont need `RegisterStartupScript` as you already have your function in JS file. `RegisterStartupScript` is used when you want to add JS function to the page from the server side.

Comment: `OnClientClick` should work. `Click` expects a server side method.

Comment: thanks. i have updated the answer. I guess it is onClick and not click.

Comment: My button is an aspx button and its not working .It just postbacks

Comment: I do understand your button is asp button. I have updated the answer. see if it helps.

Comment: @vini: if you want the postback not to happen, you should return false from your function or the onclick-code. If you don't need the postback, it's even easier if you just post a non-server-side control on your ASPX, as in `<input type="submit" onclick="alert('hello');return false;">`.

Comment: @vini : I have added complete code in there now. That should get you going.

Comment: yup it works now =) however the page at the back gets refreshed

Comment: Did you comment out  btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); from your cs file?