# c# with Youtube Javascript API?

Tags: c#, javascript, youtube

I'm playing with my application which runs under .net 4 and would like to watch youtube videos there (the application is something like a MediaCenter).

I also would like to play/pause with buttons, so for my understanding I could use youtube's api for javascript?

I'm currently using Webbrowser control to show videos or is a better solution out there?

Thanks for your advises
Regards

Comment: Look at YouTube's API. This has nothing to do with .NET, it's JavaScript. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: yes, I'm using .net youtube api for searching/retrieving video feeds and as I wrote above.I'm then using webbrowser control to display them. But now I'm stuck to control this video, I have to use .net buttons to play/pause, so the only way seems to call javascript from c# or may I'm wrong?

Comment: Call JavaScript from the button itself.

Comment: You're right - you should call the JavaScript API from the C# code of the form. The other way would be NOT to use the YouTube player: get the raw video from YouTube and play it in a different video player.

Comment: @Diodeus Like at this topic? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861321/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-c-sharp-code-behind-on-asp-net-button-cli) "@"MiMo you mean receiving the raw video stream?do you have a link how to achieve this? Thanks!